# Form input value not being passed in action

Tags: php, wordpress, forms, parameter-passing, wordpress-shortcode

I have a form with an affiliate URL in the action. I am passing the page slug / URL with no issues. The only issue I have is when I am trying to pass the user input value ($_POST["domaininput"])

What I want is that what the user writes in the input field, loads in the action url just after the parameter: domainToCheck=

I have tried the get method but no luck either. Any help is much appreciated

```
function domain_search_box(){

    global $wp;
    $current_slug = add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request );
    $current_url = home_url( add_query_arg( array(), $wp->request ) );
    
    if($current_slug == "") {
        $current_slug = $current_url;
    }

    $result = '<form class="form-wrapper cf" action="https://www.kqzyfj.com/click-5628080-11774111?aid=11774111&pid=5628080&sid='.$current_slug.'&url=https://www.godaddy.com/domains/searchresults.aspx?domainToCheck='.$_POST["domaininput"].'&checkAvail=1/" method="post"><input name="domaininput" id="domaininput" type="text" placeholder="Search for a Domain" required>
    <button type="submit">Search</button></form>';

    return $result;
}

add_shortcode( 'domain_search_box', 'domain_search_box' );
```

Comment: So you used this shortcode on a page that you _reach_ by submitting a form with method POST, that contained a field named `domaininput`? Otherwise, were do you expect `$_POST["domaininput"]` to come from here?

Comment: @CBroe thanks for replying. $_POST["domaininput"] value needs to be inserted in the action URL behind domainToCheck=

Comment: I am not asking where you want to put it, but where it is supposed to _come from_.

Answer (score 0):

As my understanding you want the user to input text then it will be in the

url ex: `domain.com?input=value`

First of all, the form should be `GET`

named input with ‘`domainToCheck`’

And make a submit button

Make action empty `action`=””